# double free or corruption (out) - C++

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to Implement Parallel Reduction using Min, Max, Sum and Average in CUDA.

This is my main code snippet as of now.

```
int main()
{
    const auto count = 8;
    const int size = count * sizeof(int);
    int h[] = {13, 27, 15, 14, 33, 2, 24, 6};

    int* d;
    int choice = 0;
    do{
        cout <<"\n ---MENU--- \n";
        cout <<"1. Find Sum of Numbers in Array\n";
        cout <<"2. Find Max of Array\n";
        cout <<"3. Find Min of Array\n";
        cout <<"4. Find Average of Array\n";
        cout <<"5. Exit\n";
        cout <<"Enter your Choice : ";
        cin >> choice;
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                cudaMalloc(&d, size);
                cudaMemcpy(d, h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

                sum <<<1, count / 2 >>>(d);

                int result;
                cudaMemcpy(&result, d, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

                cout << "Sum is " << result << endl;

                getchar();

                cudaFree(d);
                delete[] h;
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Wrong Input!! Try Again!";
                break;
        }
    }while(choice != 5);
return 0;
}
```

This is my CUDA Kernel for SUM:

```
__global__ void sum(int* input)
{
    const int tid = threadIdx.x;
    auto step_size = 1;
    int number_of_threads = blockDim.x;

    while (number_of_threads > 0)
    {
        if (tid < number_of_threads) // still alive?
        {
            const auto fst = tid * step_size * 2;
            const auto snd = fst + step_size;
            input[fst] += input[snd];
        }

        step_size <<= 1; 
        number_of_threads >>= 1;
    }
}
```

On running the program, I am getting this as OUTPUT:

[image]

How do I solve this issue? Please help me.

Comment: Don't ignore your warnings?

Comment: You need to read up on automatic allocation.

Comment: Did you run it under Valgrind?  That's the usual way to diagnose errors in allocation and deallocation.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ignore the compiler warnings. You are calling `delete[]` on a non-dynamically-allocated array. This is **undefined behavior** and likely the cause of your core dump.

You don't need to call `delete[]` for arrays on the stack.

Comment: Thanks!! Removal of delete[] helped me!